Fraunhofer temporal far-field condition for dispersive Fourier transform (DFT) technique
I am trying to understand the dispersive Fourier transform (DFT) technique for spectral characterization of pulses. In the literature, I found this far-field condition from Fraunhofer approximation in temporal domain which has to be satisfied to determine the required amount of dispersion:
$$
t_0^2 << |2\beta_2 z| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$
This was from 'Godin, Thomas, et al. "Recent advances on time-stretch dispersive Fourier transform and its applications." Advances in Physics: X 7.1 (2022): 2067487.'
In another article, I found this condition showing the required amount of dispersive stretching,
$$
\frac{\lambda^2 t_0}{2\pi c B}<< |\beta_2 z|~~~~~~~~~~~(2)
$$
This condition (2) is from the article 'Runge, Antoine FJ, et al. "Coherence and shot-to-shot spectral fluctuations in noise-like ultrafast fiber lasers." Optics Letters 38.21 (2013): 4327-4330.'
Here, $t_0$ is the pulse width, $\beta_2 z$ accounts for the total group velocity dispersion experienced by the pulse, $B$ is the pulse spectral bandwidth, $\lambda$ is the central wavelength of the pulse, and $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum.
I would like to know why there is a bandwidth dependence in the equation (2). Also, can anyone help me with how the temporal analogue of the Fraunhofer condition has been derived? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Please define the quantities in your expressions.
